# How to set default gateway after boot

Tags: debian, boot, defaults, gateway, pppd

I have setup raspberrypi zero w running raspbian as wifi router. I have PPPoE broadband connection. After setting up `pppoeconf , hostapd & dnsmasq`. I get this routing table ::

```
route -n

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         U     0      0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         U     0      0        0 ppp0
10.1.0.1        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.43.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
```

After executing :: `sudo route add default gw 10.1.0.1 ppp0`. Internet starts working. Routing table now becomes ::

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.1.0.1        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 ppp0
0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         U     0      0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         U     0      0        0 ppp0
10.1.0.1        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.43.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
```

So, I tried to set `route add default gw 10.1.0.1 ppp0` command to run on boot.
I added this to `/etc/rc.local`. Didn't work ; 
Then to `/etc/network/interfaces`.  Didn't work ; 
To `/etc/ppp/ip-up.d/0clampmss`. Didn't work ;
To `sudo crontab -e` . `@reboot`. Didn't work.

I did all this with `/bin/ip route change default via 10.1.0.1 dev ppp0`. But still it didn't work.

How do I set default gateway 10.1.0.1 ppp0 on boot so that I don't need to run it manually everytime ?

Comment: Do you get internet access if instead of adding a new default route you remove the already present eth0 default route? If yes, you'd better work towards getting rid of that in the first place.

Comment: You can only add the default route after the PPPoE connection is established. `pppd` has the option `defaultroute` for this (see `man pppd`), but I don't know how `pppoeconf` allows to set this option. So find whereever it stores the `pppd` options, and modify accordingly.